# Nexus3: Push to Docker Group Repo

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

I have Nexusv3.6 and created a Docker repo `docker-repo` (type: hosted) and a Docker group `docker-group` (type: group).
For both I enabled *HTTPS connector*:[image]

`docker-repo` on Port `8101` and `docker-group` on Port `8102`.

I added `docker-repo` to my `docker-group`.

Now I am able to push/pull an image to/from `docker-repo` directly like:

```
docker push myhost.com:8101/mymimage:latest
```

But when I try to push to the group like this:

```
docker push myhost.com:8102/docker-repo/mymimage:latest
```

I get an error saying: `error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value`

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official [documentation about repository groups for docker](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/private-registry-for-docker/repository-groups-for-docker):

> A repository group is the recommended way to expose all your
>   repositories for **read** access to your users.

and, from the documentation about [pushing images in private registries](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/private-registry-for-docker/pushing-images)

> You can not push to a repository group or a proxy repository.

Comment: True enough today, but the idea does have some merit.  See here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10471

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem with NGINX as follows:
**Updated**.

In the following example, "repository/docker" is a group that combines docker-proxy and docker-hosted repositories.

All `HEAD`* and `GET` requests are proxied to the docker repository group (hosted + proxy).
All "changing" requests are proxied to the docker-hosted repository  directly.
*One exception. `HEAD /v2/.../blobs/` should be proxied to the hosted repo because it called before push blobs to the hosted repo and we have to check the blob existence in the hosted repo. Otherwise we get an error: `blob unknown: blob unknown to registry`

```
    server {
        listen   *:443 default_server ssl;

.........................

        location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/[^/]+/?[^/]+/blobs/ {
            if ($request_method ~* (POST|PUT|DELETE|PATCH|HEAD) ) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-hosted/$1 last;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker/$1 last;
        }

        location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/ {
            if ($request_method ~* (POST|PUT|DELETE|PATCH) ) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-hosted/$1 last;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker/$1 last;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        }
    }
```

You can verify the settings by running:

```sh
# pull via proxy
docker pull nexus.your.domain/ubuntu

# push to the hosted repository
docker push nexus.your.domain/ubuntu
```

Comment: Even we want to pull from the group, you deserve +1. If you figure out how to pull from docker group repository instead of proxy, please ping me.

Comment: Did not quite understand your question.  In my example `repository/docker` this is the group.

Comment: Can someone translate it into apache httpd?